# How to submit Spark jobs to Apache Livy?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, livy

I am trying to understand how to submit Spark job to Apache Livy.

I added the following API to my POM.xml:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.cloudera.livy</groupId>
     <artifactId>livy-api</artifactId>
     <version>0.3.0</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.cloudera.livy</groupId>
     <artifactId>livy-scala-api_2.11</artifactId>
     <version>0.3.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Then I have the following code in Spark that I want to submit to Livy on request.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
                            .appName("Test")
                            .master("local[*]")
                            .getOrCreate()


    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

    implicit val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext

    // ...
  }
}
```

To have the following code that creates a `LivyClient` instance and uploads the application code to the Spark context:

```
val client = new LivyClientBuilder()
  .setURI(new URI(livyUrl))
  .build()

try {
  client.uploadJar(new File(testJarPath)).get()

  client.submit(new Test())

} finally {
  client.stop(true)
}
```

However, the problem is that the code of `Test` is not adapted to be used with Apache Livy.

How can I adjust the code of `Test` object in order to be able to run `client.submit(new Test())`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Test` class needs to implement Livy's `Job` interface and you need to implement its `call` method in your `Test` class, from where you will get access to jobContext/SparkContext. You can then pass the instance of `Test` in the `submit` method

You don't have to create SparkSession by yourself, Livy will create it on the cluster and you can access that context in your `call` method.

You can find more detailed information on Livy's programmatic API here: https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/programmatic-api.html

Here's a sample implementation of Test Class:

```
import com.cloudera.livy.{Job, JobContext}

class Test extends Job[Int]{

  override def call(jc: JobContext): Int = {

    val spark = jc.sparkSession()

    // Do anything with SparkSession

    1 //Return value
  }
}
```

Comment: I use `import org.apache.livy._` to make it working, instead of `com.cloudera....`

Comment: I opened a new thread related to this question. You may want to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224564/how-to-pass-parameters-to-sparksession-using-apache-livy