# How to set Spark configuration properties using Apache Livy?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, livy

I don't know how to pass SparkSession parameters programmatically when submitting Spark job to Apache Livy:

This is the Test Spark job:

```
class Test extends Job[Int]{

  override def call(jc: JobContext): Int = {

    val spark = jc.sparkSession()

    // ...

  }
}
```

This is how this Spark job is submitted to Livy:

```
val client = new LivyClientBuilder()
  .setURI(new URI(livyUrl))
  .build()

try {
  client.uploadJar(new File(testJarPath)).get()

  client.submit(new Test())

} finally {
  client.stop(true)
}
```

How can I pass the following configuration parameters to SparkSession?

```
  .config("es.nodes","1localhost")
  .config("es.port",9200)
  .config("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
  .config("es.index.auto.create","true")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that easily through the `LivyClientBuilder` like this:

```
val client = new LivyClientBuilder()
  .setURI(new URI(livyUrl))
  .setConf("es.nodes","1localhost")
  .setConf("key", "value")
  .build()
```

Answer (score 2):

Configuration parameters can be set to `LivyClientBuilder` using

```
public LivyClientBuilder setConf(String key, String value)
```

so that your code starts with:

```
val client = new LivyClientBuilder()
  .setURI(new URI(livyUrl))
  .setConf("es.nodes","1localhost")
  .setConf("es.port",9200)
  .setConf("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
  .setConf("es.index.auto.create","true")
  .build()
```

Comment: I am trying to use the conf field in the [livy post call](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html) to set `spark.network.timeout` to `600s`. Is there a way to verify the same whether the value got correctly set or not? I have a [question as well on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690915/how-to-check-spark-config-for-an-application-in-ambari-ui-posted-with-livy)

Comment: I am in the same boat, posting the conf via the REST API, and it appears Livy is not passing it to the spark context

Answer (score 0):

`LivyClientBuilder.setConf` will not work, I think. Because Livy will modify all configs not starting with `spark.`. And Spark cannot read the modified config. [See here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/3b9bbefbaf8ddb3116952caf8c15b97d676386a7/rsc/src/main/java/org/apache/livy/rsc/ContextLauncher.java#L273)

```java
private static File writeConfToFile(RSCConf conf) throws IOException {
    Properties confView = new Properties();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : conf) {
      String key = e.getKey();
      if (!key.startsWith(RSCConf.SPARK_CONF_PREFIX)) {
        key = RSCConf.LIVY_SPARK_PREFIX + key;
      }
      confView.setProperty(key, e.getValue());
    }
 ...
}
```

So the answer is quite simple: add `spark.` to all es configs, like this,

```java
  .config("spark.es.nodes","1localhost")
  .config("spark.es.port",9200)
  .config("spark.es.nodes.wan.only","true")
  .config("spark.es.index.auto.create","true")
```

Don't know it is elastic-spark does the compatibility job, or spark. It just works.

[image: Spark UI shows the configs]

PS: I've tried with the REST API, and it works. But not with the Programmatic API.